# Group by with loop in R

Tags: r, function

Using USPersonalExpenditure, I'm trying to loop through the years, calculate the percentage change between each one for each row individually and then find the cumulative percentage growth.

So far, I've got:

```
library(dplyr)    
xyz <- USPersonalExpenditure
calc_tot <- function(xyz) {
    yr1 <- (xyz$1945-xyz$1940)/xyz$1940
    yr2 <- (xyz$1950-xyz$1945)/xyz$1945
    yr3 <- (xyz$1955-xyz$1950)/xyz$1950
    yr4 <- (xyz$1960-xyz$1955)/xyz$1955
    return(sum(yr1, yr2, yr3, yr4))
}
new_xyz %>%
    xyz %>%
    calc_tot
```

This returns:

```
[1] 0.01026966
```

which doesn't show the individual rows or the cumulative totals.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `new_xyz` ? Your function does not use `xyz` value passed at all. `yr1 <- (1945-1940)/1940` uses the number 1945 and 1940. Aren't they supposed to be columns of `xyz` ?

Comment: This is why I'm getting confused. My stages are such: 1. calculate the percentages between the columns for each row 2. add them together 3. create new data table showing just the row titles and the accumulated percentages. I'll edit the code above to reflect your comment.

Comment: I've altered it and now it's showing errors on all the lines yr1-yr4.

Comment: R functions only return the value of the last evaluation. So `sum` returns a single value. Hence no surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand the cumulative percentage growth part but you can calculate percentage growth within years by -

```
calc_tot <- function(xyz) {
  (xyz[, -1] - xyz[, -ncol(xyz)])/xyz[, -ncol(xyz)]
}

calc_tot(xyz)

#                     1945  1950  1955  1960
#Food and Tobacco    1.005 0.339 0.228 0.186
#Household Operation 0.476 0.871 0.259 0.266
#Medical and Health  0.632 0.686 0.442 0.507
#Personal Care       0.904 0.237 0.388 0.588
#Private Education   1.856 0.848 0.444 0.400
```

Note that you have one column less than the original input. The first column in the output is basically `(1945-1940)/1940` and so on for other columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should have been:

```
calc_tot <- function(xyz) {
    yr1 <- (xyz$1945-xyz$1940)/xyz$1940
    yr2 <- (xyz$1950-xyz$1945)/xyz$1945
    yr3 <- (xyz$1955-xyz$1950)/xyz$1950
    yr4 <- (xyz$1960-xyz$1955)/xyz$1955
    return(sum(yr1, yr2, yr3, yr4))
}
new_xyz <-  xyz %>%
              calc_tot
```

Perhaps you need to understand that the assignment operation (`<-`) is quite different than function composition (`%>%`).